# Insert degree symbol in text box (problem exporting to .eps instead of a degree symbom I get a quotation mark!)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, text-element

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I need to export a map to .eps file format. In this map I need to include a text box with some lat. and lon. coordinates. I´m using the keybord symbol º and arial (this inserts a perfect degree symbol). In the layout view it is perfect but when I export the map to .eps. Instead of the degree symbol I get a quotation mark: "

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On export check Convert marker symbols to polygons and Embed all document fonts.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you help